# Java - Удаление элемента из бинарного дерева, хранящегося в массиве

Tags: java

Не могу понять, как удалить ноду из бинарного дерева, хранящегося в массиве (не бинарное дерево поиска, а просто бинарное дерево).
Удаляю ноду в том случае, если у ноды только один потомок, левый или правый, либо нет потомков вообще. Методы обхода дерева тоже реализованы, не стал вставлять для краткости.

```
public class ArrayBinaryTree<E> extends AbstractBinaryTree<E> {
ArrayList<NodeImpl<E>> nodesArray = new ArrayList<>();

public Node<E> left(Node<E> p) {
    if (nodesArray.get(nodesArray.indexOf(p) * 2 + 1) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return nodesArray.get(nodesArray.indexOf(p) * 2 + 1);
}

public Node<E> right(Node<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (nodesArray.get(nodesArray.indexOf(p) * 2 + 2) == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return nodesArray.get(nodesArray.indexOf(p) * 2 + 2);
}

@Override
public Node<E> addLeft(Node<E> n, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (nodesArray.get((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 1) != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This node already has left node");
    }

    nodesArray.set((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 1, new NodeImpl<>(e));
    return nodesArray.get((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 1);
}

public Node<E> addRight(Node<E> n, E e) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (nodesArray.get((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 2) != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This node already has right node");
    }

    nodesArray.set((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 2, new NodeImpl<>(e));
    return nodesArray.get((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 2);
}

public Node<E> root() {

    if (nodesArray.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return nodesArray.get(0);
    }
}

public Node<E> parent(Node<E> n) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (n == nodesArray.get(0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This is root node");
    } else {
        return nodesArray.get(((nodesArray.indexOf(n) - 1) / 2));  
    }
}

public Node<E> addRoot(E e) throws IllegalStateException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        nodesArray.add(i, null);
    }

    if (root() != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This tree already have root node");
    } else {
        nodesArray.add(0, new NodeImpl<>(e));
        return root();
    }
}
```

Далее необходимо написать метод по удалению ноды. Не могу понять, как сдвинуть элементы массива `nodesArray`, чтобы удалить ноду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так реализовать: если потомок один, то вызывается рекурсивный метод "подтягивания" потомка на место родительской ноды.

```
public void removeNode(Node<E> n) {
    int nodeIndex=nodesArray.indexOf(n);
        Node<E> left=left(n);
        Node<E> right=right(n);
        Node<E> son;
        boolean leftFirst=false;
        if (left==null) {
            if (right==null) {
                //no sons
                nodesArray.set(nodeIndex,null);
                return;
            } else {
                son=right;
                leftFirst=true;
            }
        } else {
            if (right==null) {
                son=left;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("This node has two sons");
            }
        }
        pullUp(nodeIndex,son,leftFirst);
    }

public void pullUp(int index, Node<E> n, boolean leftFirst) {
    Node<E> left=left(n);
    Node<E> right=right(n);
    nodesArray.set(nodesArray.indexOf(n),null);
    nodesArray.set(index,n);
    if (leftFirst) {
            if (left!=null) pullUp(index*2+1,left,leftFirst);
            if (right!=null) pullUp(index*2+2,right,leftFirst);
        } else {
            if (right!=null) pullUp(index*2+2,right,leftFirst);
            if (left!=null) pullUp(index*2+1,left,leftFirst);
        }
}
```

В таком виде не скомпилируется `nodesArray.set(index,n)`, т.к. `ArrayList` параметризован `NodeImpl<E>` у Вас (не вижу причин, почему не `Node<E>`).

В процессе проверки обнаружил неприятную особенность реализации: когда вычисляется `(nodesArray.get(nodesArray.indexOf(p) * 2 + 2)` можно получить 0, если p не найден. Возможно, стоит добавить проверку на `nodesArray.indexOf(p)!=-1`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Этот вариант подошёл бы, если бы у всех потомков удалённой ноды было бы по одному сыну. А тут суть в том, что во избежание двусмысленности удалять мы можем только ноду с одним сыном, но у её потомков нет такого ограничения. И из-за этого я уже не могу просто подтягивать ноды на место их парента, оно может быть уже занято. Для примера дерево 1-правый-2-правый-3-правый и левый-4,5. Удаляем 2, получаем 1-правый-3-правый и левый-4,5.

Comment: Так как в методе `pullUp` два рекурсивных вызова, код работает с потомками без ограничений. Но важен порядок рекурсивных вызовов: если у удаляемой ноды одинокий левый сын, значит вся параллельная ему правая ветка свободна: сначала перенесём туда всех правых потомков сына, потом подтянем левых потомков на освободившиеся места. В случае правого сына наоборот. Добавил переменную `boolean leftFirst`, определяющую порядок рекурсивных вызовов.

Comment: Применительно к Вашему примеру порядок действий будет таким: подтянем 3 на место 2, подтянем 4 на свободное место левого потомка, подтянем 5 на бывшее место 3. Рекурсивные вызовы идут после подтягивания родителя, поэтому потомок пишется на освободившееся место.

Comment: Да, вижу, так должно работать. Сегодня попробую реализовать и отпишусь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> Далее необходимо написать метод по удалению ноды. Не могу понять, как сдвинуть элементы массива nodesArray, чтобы удалить ноду.

Зачем их сдвигать? У вас же доступ к детям идет по индексу

```
  if (nodesArray.get(nodesArray.indexOf(p) * 2 + 2) == null)
  if (nodesArray.get((nodesArray.indexOf(n) * 2) + 1) != null)
```

т.е. если вы сдвинете один, то придется двигать и остальные, тогда придется думать о новой динамической индексации (хрен знает какой).

По делу предложу вам 2 варианта:

1. Создать наследника Node - DeletedNode, в котором переопределить все методы и описать логику обращения к удаленному элементу (кидать exception, null или ещё что-то)
2. Просто заменять удаленный элемент на null

То же самое к потомку ноды

Comment: В том то и дело, что при удалении годы мне необходимо сохранить структуру дерева, заменить на null можно только листья, у них нет потомков. При удалении ноды у которой есть парент и есть сын мне нужно сохранить связь. Как пример, если бы я реализовывал дерево при помощи ссылок, то я бы просто изменил бы ссылку на сына в паренте удаляемой ноды на  сына удаляемой ноды. А для того чтобы сделать это при хранении в массиве мне нужно, как вы и сказали, думать об индексации, заменить удаленный на его сына, а затем каким-то образом сдвинуть всех его потомков. И вот с этим сдвигом потомков я и застрял.